# Mat Table not displaying any data, shows white bar

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to display a table beside a side-menu. I tried to use examples from Angular Materials but my page just shows a white bar, not even the headers are shown. I have imported MatTableModule in app.module.ts & the module in the 2nd page(user.module.ts). I am not sure which part I am missing on. When i created users page via CLI( ionic g page users),users.module.ts is also created. Therefore i am not sure where should i import the modules to.

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'  
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,MatTableModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, MatSliderModule],
  exports: [MatSliderModule],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  public appPages = [
    { title: 'Home', url: '/', icon: 'home' },
    { title: 'Edit Users', url: '/users', icon: 'people' },
    { title: 'Edit Drives', url: '/drive', icon: 'car' },
    { title: 'Export MTRAC', url: '/mtrac', icon: 'document' },
  ];
  constructor() {}
}


export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];

export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}
```

user.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { UsersPageRoutingModule } from './users-routing.module';

import { UsersPage } from './users.page';

import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    UsersPageRoutingModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatTableModule,
  ],
  declarations: [UsersPage]
})
export class UsersPageModule {}
```

users.page.html

```
    <ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Edit Users</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
          The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->
  
    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
  
  
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Please provide the `component.ts` code that corresponds to `users.page.html`.

Comment: @N.F. when i generated the page it only generated users.page.ts,users.page.spec.ts,users.page.scss,users.page.html,users.module.ts & users-routing.module.ts. Am i supposed to add a component file in the folder too?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill the `dataSource` in the `component.ts` of the html file which refers to the `users.page.html`.

Check this example on stackblitz. It creates a simple `mat-table`.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/dlxbkjqaoba?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts